# CSS :hover on button not working within already hovered div

Tags: css, sass, hover

I have a div appearing on top of an image when I hover the image itself. The div contains two divs (buttons) that also have a :hover that changes their color and sets the cursor to the pointer.

The issue is the hovering on the button doesn't trigger the hover.

Also, it seems that hovering on the image at the bottom where the btn_container will appear doesn't trigger to first :hover and doesn't make the btn_container appear.

```
//HTML
 <div class="container">
  <img src="src">
  <div class="btn_container">
    <div class=" btn">
      <p>Select</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <p>Preview</p>
    </div>
  </div>
      
//SCSS
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  .btn_container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: var(--dark-purple-trans);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    align-items: center;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
  }
  img:hover + .btn_container,
  .btn_container > * {
    display: flex;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .btn {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    height: 14px;
    background: var(--yellow-medium);
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--white);
    font-family: roboto;
    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background: var(--red);
      color: var(--white);
    }
  }
}
```

Preview, button hovering not working:

[image]

If I force the hover on the img using the inspector, the button hovering seems to work:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in classes `img:hover + .btn_container` and `.btn_container > *`.

Here is the updated scss:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

  img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 0;
  }

  &:hover .btn_container {
    display: flex;
  }

  .btn_container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: var(--dark-purple-trans);
    border: none;
  }

  .btn {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    color: var(--white);
    font-family: roboto;
    background-color: var(--yellow-medium);
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
      color: var(--white);
      background-color: var(--red);
    }
  }
}
```

You can view it in action here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/demartini/full/dyGvPaG)

Comment: This one worked. The issue got fixed by attaching the :hover to the container directly isntead of the img.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using opacity instead of display to toggle visibility of the btn_container and added a hover to btn_container and it seemed to work: https://jsfiddle.net/pr8dxe2g/1/

```
  .btn_container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: var(--dark-purple-trans);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }

  img:hover + .btn_container,
  .btn_container:hover,
  .btn_container > * {
    display: flex;
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
```

There may be some issue with your current code with the fact that the the img div has a higher stack-order if the display is set to none initially, however I am not certain so if anyone knows I would like to know why this is the case as well.